# JTable swing exception

Tags: csv, netbeans, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, awt-eventqueue

this is a follow up to a question I asked about a day ago, I have been trying to debug the code with no success, but basically the application is supposed to allow the user to select the CSV they want to import or view, after selecting the file they will only view the contents of the Csv in a JTable. currently I can view the data in the csv but it doesn't show in the Jtable as it is supposed to. here is the code for the program below, with the exception that netbeans throws at me.

```
public class Asist_payment_import_v1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private final JTable Table;

public Asist_payment_import_v1(){
    super(new BorderLayout(3,3));


    this.Table = new JTable(new MiModel());
    this.Table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(700,70));
    this.Table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JPanel ButtonOpen = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    //the below  utton will be used to upload csv data to Database, the action listener should connect to the db, and pass data into the Db.
    //JPanel ButtonUpload = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    JButton open_file = new JButton("Open");
    JButton save_file = new JButton("Save");

    ButtonOpen.add(open_file);
    add(ButtonOpen, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    open_file.addActionListener(this);
    save_file.addActionListener(this);

    //create scrollPane to this Panel
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(Table);

    //add the scroll pane to this pane
    add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add Border
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event)
{

    JFileChooser file_chooser = new JFileChooser();
    boolean pressed = true;

    if(pressed)
    {
        int ReturnVal = file_chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        CSVFile Rd = new CSVFile();

        MiModel NewModel = new MiModel();
        this.Table.setModel(NewModel);// to set the Table model

        File DataFile = file_chooser.getSelectedFile();
        ArrayList<String[]> rs2 = Rd.ReadCSVFile(DataFile);

        NewModel.AddCSVData(rs2);
        System.out.println("Rows: " +NewModel.getRowCount());
        System.out.println("Cols: " +NewModel.getColumnCount());

    }
}


public class CSVFile
{
    private ArrayList<String[]> Rs = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] OneRow;

    public ArrayList<String[]> ReadCSVFile(File DataFile){
        try{
            BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(DataFile));

            while(brd.readLine()!= null){
                String st = brd.readLine();
                OneRow = st.split(",");
                Rs.add(OneRow);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
                }
    }//end try 
        catch(Exception ex){
        String errmsg = ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println("File not Found: "+errmsg);
    }//end exception handling
    return Rs;
  }//End of ArrayList_readCSVFile class
}//End of CSVFile class

private static void createAndShowGui()
{
    //setup Window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PaymentImport");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //setup the conentPane
    Asist_payment_import_v1 newContentPane = new Asist_payment_import_v1();
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //display the window
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


class MiModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private String [] columnNames = {"Nr","LinkId","Ammount","PayDate","Month","Year","Printed","User","RefNo","ShortSwi",
                                    "BranchNo","SyncHQ","SyncBranch","SysDateStamp","RDReason","UnderPrice","PaydMark","RecieptPrinted"};

    private ArrayList<String[]>Data = new ArrayList<>();

    public void AddCSVData(ArrayList<String[]> DataIn){
        this.Data = DataIn;
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount(){
        return Data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col){
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        return Data.get(row)[col];
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // schedule a job for the event-despatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    }); } }
```

the exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
at asist_payment_import_v1.Asist_payment_import_v1$MiModel.getValueAt(Asist_payment_import_v1.java:150)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5706)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

here is part of the results which show on the netbeans output panel, instead of the JTable:

```
[2019017, 288633, 69.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19061)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:13", "", 54.00, 
20171127]
[2019019, 288638, 42.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19061)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:13", "", 27.00, 
20171127]
[2019021, 315068, 42.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19061)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:14", "", 27.00, 
20171127]
[2019023, 294133, 69.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19061)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:14", "", 54.00, 
20171127]
[2019025, 288623, 130.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19063)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:30", "", 1068.80, 
20171127]
[2019027, 288625, 105.00, 20171127, 11, 2017, "False", "Annamarie", "Group 
Payment (19063)", "False", "All", 0, , , "2017-11-27 09:43:31", "", 855.00, 
20171127]
Rows: 690551
Cols: 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a solution for this question, I made alterations to my CSV Method that reads the csv data.. here are the changes made

```
public class CSVFile
{
    private ArrayList<String[]> arrLs = new ArrayList<>();
    private Object OneRow;

    public ArrayList<String[]> ReadCSVFile(File DataFile)
    {
        try
        {    
            //BufferedReader to Read through CSV Contents
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(DataFile));
            String line;

            // while loop to read through the data, while bufferedreader is not null-do .... 
            while(reader.readLine()!= null)
            {
                try
                {
                    line = reader.readLine();

                    if(line != null)
                    {
                        String[] array = line.split(",");

                        for(String result:array)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(OneRow[2]+");
                            System.out.println(result);
                        }
                    }                      
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(reader == null)
                    {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                }

                //if statement needed in the case the 
                //Selected CSV has more than the required number of ColumnHeaders
                //and the BufferedReader needs to skip the first Row, as this is the 
                //columnHeaders and they cannot be included again
                String read = reader.readLine();//bufferedreader string variable
                OneRow = read.split(",");
                arrLs.add((String[]) OneRow);
                // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
            }//end try 
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 String errmsg = ex.getMessage();
                 //System.out.println("File not Found: "+errmsg);
            }    // end exception handling

            return (ArrayList<String[]>) arrLs;
        }   //End of ArrayList_readCSVFile class
    } //End of CSVFile class
}
```

This allowed me to view the csv data in the JTable which was the main issue here